# React native - how do you access the value that the slider is on in another component (function)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slider, expo

Here is my code for the slider:

```
class RedSlider extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      percentage: 100,
      minPercentage: 0,
      maxPerentage: 100,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {percentage} = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <Slider
                style={{ width: 300}}
                step={1}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={100}
                value={this.state.percentage}
                thumbTintColor='black'
                maximumTrackTintColor='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
                minimumTrackTintColor='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
                onValueChange={val => this.setState({ percentage: val })}
            />
            <View style={styles.textCon}>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>{this.state.minPercentage}%</Text>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>
                    {this.state.percentage + '%'}   
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>{this.state.maxPerentage}%</Text> 
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I reference the slider in a function that is a certain screen for my app. I can successfully display the slider and everything, so I am good on that front. I call the slider like so, within the return():

```
<RedSlider/>
```

However, how do I access the value of the slider within the screen function, so that I can actually use the slider. I just want to have that percentage value. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have made an example of an uncontrolled component so state is stored local to that component.

If you want to pass the value up to the parent you can have another onChange callback that passes the value higher.

```
class RedSlider extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      percentage: 100,
      minPercentage: 0,
      maxPercentage: 100,
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }

  onChange (val) {
    this.setState({ percentage: val })
    props.onValueChange(val)
  } 

  render() {
    const {percentage} = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <Slider
                style={{ width: 300}}
                step={1}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={100}
                value={this.state.percentage}
                thumbTintColor='black'
                maximumTrackTintColor='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
                minimumTrackTintColor='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
                onValueChange={onChange}
            />
            <View style={styles.textCon}>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>{this.state.minPercentage}%</Text>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>
                    {this.state.percentage + '%'}   
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>{this.state.maxPercentage}%</Text> 
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

However, it's generally better to minimize local state where unnecessary and use a controlled component and only store the component on the parent. This is because the component and parent's values can get out of sync.

```
class RedSlider extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      minPercentage: 0,
      maxPercentage: 100,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Slider
                style={{ width: 300}}
                step={1}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={100}
                value={this.props.percentage} // get percentage directly from the parent. 
                thumbTintColor='black'
                maximumTrackTintColor='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
                minimumTrackTintColor='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
                onValueChange={val => this.props.onValueChange({ percentage: val })} // send changes to the parent by passing a callback to this component
            />
            <View style={styles.textCon}>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>{this.state.minPercentage}%</Text>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>
                    {this.state.percentage + '%'}   
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.colorBlack}>{this.state.maxPercentage}%</Text> 
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Checkout the [react docs on controlled and uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) for more info.